# Apache SSL with Multiple Virtualhost

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, ssl, https

I have a VPS from DO with one ip address. I'm managing multiple domain via Apache Virtual Hosts, and now, I must setup a virtual host with SSL support. I created a self-signed ssl certificate to test virtual host.

I can see content of example1.com with https when I connected https://example1.com but I can see content of example1.com too when I connected to https://example2.com although example2.com has not ssl configuration at server's conf file.

example1.com configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    basic example1.com http conf such as DocumentRoot, ServerName
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    example1.com https conf

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/example1.com-ssl-server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/example1.com-ssl-server.key
</VirtualHost>
```

example2.com configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    basic example2.com http conf such as DocumentRoot, ServerName
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I can see content of example1.com too when I connected to https://example2.com although example2.com has not ssl configuration at server's conf file.

That happens precisely *because* example2.com doesn't have a SSL configuration. By default, if there's no VirtualHost with the exact server name, then Apache [will use the *first* VirtualHost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html) for the same port.

(That's why Debian, for example, uses "000-default.conf" for the default vhost, so that it would always go before anything else.)

Comment: So should I set ssl configuration to all virtualhosts which I don't want to have https connection?

Comment: @KaanKölköy: Well, these days you _do_ want a https connection for all of them. Really. But the other way is to have a special "fallback" VirtualHost with just an error message (and no ServerName), and put it before all other vhosts.

Comment: I already have a fallback virtualhost both for *:80 and *:443, but this time, I cannot connect to https://example1.com. Did I understand you wrong?